# How to remove quotes from an Object, Java

Tags: java, string, object, types, stack

I am writing an Interpreter in Java and am having a bit of an issue with types/ type conversion. What I have is a Stack of type Object containing the following.

```
1
error
"deadpool"
name
```

If the Interpreter sees the input "quit" it prints the stack. Which I did in the code below.

```
else if(strLine.equals("quit")){
        while(!stack.isEmpty()){
        pw.println(stack.pop());
    } 
} // quit
```

However when I print the output I would like to remove the quotes from deadpool. I thought about converting the object to a string and then trying to substring but I was not having much luck. Is there a better way to do this? I am a bit confused on how to keep popping and printing the items, while checking of the Object contains quotes, which I want to remove.

In the code, strLine is an input line from the user, stack is a stack of type Object and pw is a PrintWriter which prints to a file.

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
else if(strLine.equals("quit")){
        while(!stack.isEmpty()){
        pw.println(getObject(stack.pop()));
    } 
} // quit


private Object getObject(Object obj) {
        String objStr = null;
        if(obj instanceof String){
          String objStr = (String)obj;
          }
    Object resp = (objStr == null)? obj: objStr.replaceAll("\"","");
    return resp;
}
```